# CALCULATE column in DISTINCT filter not behaving as expected

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I'm have a measure as follows:

```
Test = CALCULATE(SUM(EthnicPopulationByLocalAuthority[Numerator]), EthnicPopulationByLocalAuthority[Geography_code] in DISTINCT(Participants[SiteDistrict Code]))
```

But the calculation is filtered on both Ethnicity and SiteDistrict Code and not only SiteDistrict Code as intended. I have created a hardcoded version of the measure which works:

```
Test2 = CALCULATE(SUM(EthnicPopulationByLocalAuthority[Numerator]), EthnicPopulationByLocalAuthority[Geography_code] in {"E09000030", "E07000066"})
```

The results in a table:

[image]

The behavior comes from Participants with SiteDistrict Code E09000030 and E07000066 only have ethnicities WhiteBritish and WhiteOther.

Essentially, I want the list {"E09000030", "E07000066"} to be generated dynamically based on the slicing done on Participants, but I can't make it work using DISTINCT. The two tables share a link to a third table ethnicities but the links are in the opposite direction, so they do not filter each other directly.

The model is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your model - maybe that needs to be optimised first.

Comment: ALLSELECTED would only work if the filtering was applied to the table directly. The reason I use DISTINCT is that the slicer is slicing directly on the Participants table on other fields than ethnicity and District Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an intermediate variable:

```
Test = 
  VAR temp = DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS(CALCULATETABLE(Participants, ALLSELECTED(Participants)), "SiteDistrict Code", [SiteDistrict Code]))
  RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(EthnicPopulationByLocalAuthority[Numerator]), EthnicPopulationByLocalAuthority[Geography_code] IN temp)
```